# Existing tools to create json object from command line

Tags: json, command-line

I would like to ask you if you know a console mode tool to simply create, save, edit and manipulate JSON objects.

I'm looking for those simple functionnalities like (example):

`create("Plants")` 
`// outputs // {"_metadata": {"name": "Plants"} }`

`Plants.add("Cactus", "Watering needs", "once every month")`

`// {"_metadata": {"name": "Plants"}, "Cactus": { "Watering needs": "once every month"}  }`

`Plants.Cactus["Watering needs"].add("General informations", "About watering", "Watering should be of x liters, and ..")`

`// {"_metadata": {"name": "Plants"}, "Cactus": { "Watering needs": {"Watering needs": "once every month", "General Informations": {"About watering":"Watering could be done with X instrument..."}  } }`

Thank you very much

Comment: With the chance to become less popular, I would like to point out, that yaml is a superset of json. So, if you plan to use the tool you ask for because you need more convenient input methods compared to writing json manually, this could be interesting. If you want to use it for example in a pipe scenario, the syntax would likely be a little more complex. Instead of ``create``, it might be ``array`` and ``object``, for example.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1955505/3266847 – and one such tool is jq. However, asking for off-site resources such as tools and software libraries is explicitly off-topic (https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: i just wrote my own tool finally